# Why is my string nil?

Tags: nim-lang

I made this simple program that reads characters until the enter key is pressed

```
var data: string

while true:
    var c = readChar(stdin) # read char

    case c
    of '\r': # if enter, stop
    break
    else: discard

    data.add(c) # add the read character to the string

echo data
```

But when it tries to `echo data`, it crashes

```
> ./program
hello
Traceback (most recent call last)
program.nim(11)          program
SIGSEGV: Illegal storage access. (Attempt to read from nil?)
```

This means `data` is nil. But every time I press enter a character, it adds the character to `data`. Something goes wrong, but where?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

data is initially nil when you define it as `var data: string`. Instead you can use `var data = ""` to make it an initialized string.

Answer (score 1):

The stream `stdin` buffers all the characters until the newline key is pressed, then it will submit the character(s). I expected the behavior to be reading direct characters.

That means that `\r` will never be the case, it will try to add a character to `data` but data is `nil`, so that fails. I thought it failed at the `echo` statement.

To demonstrate, this code works:

```
var data = ""

while true:
    var c = readChar(stdin) # read char

    case c
    of '\e': # if escape, stop
        break
    else:
        data.add(c) # add the read character to the string

echo data
```